# Android: Delete cookies in-app // How to get the browser context

Tags: android, browser

I'm failing at the moment in letting my app delete the browser cookies or some specific cookies.
The way I found was to implement the following:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

But nothing is happening. An with the method hasCookie() is get false as return. Is there no way for deleting a cookie from inside my app?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CookieSyncManager` to delete cookies from your own `WebView` widget(s).

You cannot delete cookies from third-party applications that use `WebView` or other Web rendering engines.